# Error While Exporting With Bitcode Enable Using Custom Framework

Tags: ios, bitcode, i386, swift-custom-framework

[Error While Exporting. All i386 architectures have been already removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTViT.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Show Logs` will tell you more details. Maybe your framework doesn't support i386.Use the following command to check if your framework support this architecture.

> file YourFrameworkName.framework/YourFrameworkName